# How Do I Click On A Hidden Input In Cypress With MUI and Upload An Image?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

**Problem:** I am trying to upload an image with `.selectFile`, but I am encountering an error that it is hidden, and thus it is not possible.

**React Code With Material UI:**

```
      <Button
        datacy="uploadImage"
        size={"medium"}
        disableRipple
        disableTouchRipple
        disableFocusRipple
        component="label"
        variant={"text"}
        sx={{ marginTop: { xs: 2, md: 0 }, p: 0, width: "fit-content" }}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          hidden
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        />
        {hasProfilePicture ? "Change" : "Upload"}
      </Button>
```

**HTML Component:**

```
<label role="button" datacy="uploadImage">
   <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" hidden="">
   Change
</label>
```

**Failed Attempts:**

1. `cy.get('[datacy="uploadImage"] input').selectFile("cypress/fixtures/Headshot 2.jpg");`

   Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.selectFile() failed because this element is not visible:

   This element  is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none
   Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
2. `cy.get("input[type='file'] hidden").selectFile("cypress/fixtures/Headshot 2.jpg");`

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: input[type='file'] hidden, but never found it.

**Question:** What Cypress front-end test can I write that clicks the component and uploads an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Cypress documentation says in `.selectFile`, one needs to use the `force: true` prop.

`cy.get('[datacy="uploadImage"] input').selectFile("cypress/fixtures/Headshot 2.jpg", {force: true});`

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile#On-a-hidden-input

Answer (score 5):

You should just be able to target the `<label>` element, since `<input>` is within the `.selectFile()` command is smart enough to find the input.

```js
cy.get('[datacy="uploadImage"]')
  .selectFile("cypress/fixtures/example.png")

cy.get('[datacy="uploadImage"] input')
  .its('0.files')
  .should('have.length', 1)      // passes
  .its('0.name')
  .should('eq', 'example.png')   // passes
```

Tested with

```html
<label role="button" datacy="uploadImage">
   <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" hidden="">
   Change
</label>
```

Comment: This is the proper way without relying on hacky force: true. Actual real world user clicks on wrapper/label, not on the hidden input field.